# Transfering photos and videos from Android smart phone to PC wirelessly without intermediate web site

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, bluetooth

I have Android (Samsung) based smart phone. The phone can transfer files to other smart phone using at least two ways: Bluetooth and WiFi connection. Is there a way to make my Linux PC be able to receive files (photos and video) similarly?

Comment: `without intermediate web site` you mean without a router/LAN?

Comment: @TomYan No, I mean without using, e.g., Dropbox to transfer the files.

Answer (score 3):

yup tons, just some options:

- FTP if you install an ftp app on the phone.
- smb if you install an smb app on the phone
- bluetooth if you get a bluetooth usb dongle for the pc

Comment: Good answer.  Another option is ssh.

Comment: +1 for FTP. FTPS or even SFTP are decent options if you care about security.

Comment: ADB is  Android specific way.